# Get the selected item number on the ListView

Tags: android

just wanted to ask about this since I found it really weird and I can't tell why this was happening. Well I think the code will explain it all and I just wanted to know why does this happen.

```
 record_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        SELECTED_ITEM_ON_LIST = (String)(record_list.getItemAtPosition(i));



        Log.v("Selected adapterView", String.valueOf(adapterView.getSelectedItem()));
        Log.v("Selected adapterView", String.valueOf(adapterView.getFocusedChild()));
        Log.v("Selected item position", String.valueOf(record_list.getSelectedItem()));
        Log.v("Selected item position", String.valueOf(record_list.getSelectedItemPosition()));
        Log.v("adapterView", String.valueOf(adapterView.getCount()));
        Log.v("View", String.valueOf(view.isSelected()));
        Log.v("recordList", String.valueOf(record_list.getCount()));
        Log.v("Selected item", SELECTED_ITEM_ON_LIST);
    }

});
```

and the logs:

on first click for awesome2:

```
V/Selected adapterView: null
06-07 09:45:12.398    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/Selected adapterView: null
06-07 09:45:12.408    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/Selected item position: null
06-07 09:45:12.408    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/Selected item position: -1
06-07 09:45:12.408    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/adapterView: 14
06-07 09:45:12.408    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/View: false
06-07 09:45:12.408    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/recordList: 14
06-07 09:45:12.408    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/Selected item: Awesome2
```

second click for awesome4:

```
V/Selected adapterView: null
06-07 09:45:37.099    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/Selected adapterView: null
06-07 09:45:37.108    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/Selected item position: null
06-07 09:45:37.108    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/Selected item position: -1
06-07 09:45:37.108    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/adapterView: 14
06-07 09:45:37.108    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/View: false
06-07 09:45:37.108    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/recordList: 14
06-07 09:45:37.108    8488-8488/com.test.testaudio             V/Selected item: Awesome4
```

as you can see the item position is always null for selected item and always -1 for selected item position. can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Which adapter are you using to fill your listview? Can you please paste code for how are you filling the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the item position is the third parameter of `onItemClick` (your `int i`)

int Position (starting at 0), or INVALID_POSITION if there is nothing selected.

`getSelectedItemPosition` and `getSelectedItem` returns a value != 1 and != null if the item isSelected.

The doc for `getSelectedItemPosition` says:

> returns INVALID_POSITION if there is nothing selected.

Comment: Yeah I got the part of int i. but why does it return -1 rather than 0?

Answer (score 0):

usually I use a global array (the one used to fill the adapter) and then extract the i position from that, to get the needed value:

```
//filling the adapter
itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.vedi_rubrica_riga, m_arrDati);

//on item click listener
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                ApriRubrica(m_arrDati.get(position).get("id"));

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
```

here variable i is the position of the item in the list

As I see on this [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) there is `setOnItemClickListener()` and also `setOnItemSelectedListener()` . `getSelectedItemPosition` will only work in latter case I guess.

Comment: same answer as said by blackbelt. but what I wonder is why does it returns -1 rather than 0. the part of null is already discussed by the same person I mentioned. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView record_list;
    String[] arr = {"One", "Two", "Three"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        record_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.recordList);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ArrayAdapter adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);

        record_list.setAdapter(adpt);

        record_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {



            String st = (String)record_list.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

            System.out.println("View:"+ arg1 + "item at position:"+ st);
            }

        });
    }
}
```